# Removing the first line of a textbox when a new one gets added

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I am using the following command to append text to a multiline textbox that I am using:

```
TextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & "Current status : " & currentStatus)
```

However, if there are (for example) 49 lines, I want to delete the first line when line 50 gets added.

How can I do this ?

Comment: Do you atually want a list of lines? What about wrapping long lines?

Comment: @Jodrell Well, I am making some sort of text based RPG with some visual elements embedded (health/xp bars etc etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text box has a `TextChanged` event, which is fired every time the text changes.

You can use this to count the number of lines in the text box, which is the same as the number of newline characters. If this amount exceeds your limit, you can remove the first line by locating the first newline character and remove it and everything in front of it.

I don't speak VB.Net, so I hope you can work with this and write the code.

I made an attempt any way:

```
Private Sub textBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim lineCount As Integer = textBox1.Lines.Count()

    If lineCount > 49 Then
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Substring(textBox1.Text.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine))
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, this works! I have chosen this as best answer because I can use it in a seperate textchanged sub, this way I don't ever have to look back!

Comment: Another advantage is that you can use it for multiple text boxes, if they all attach to this single event. You only have to write the code once.

Comment: To make this work I had to add `Environment.NewLine.Count()` to the substring start index so that the first `NewLine` was removed.

`textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Substring(textBox1.Text.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine)+Environment.N‌​ewLine.Count())`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `LINQ` to solve this problem. [Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vblanguage/thread/40d252ee-6506-4e52-9320-d1b266c5e573/) i have used `SKIP` and `TAKE` functions.

```
If textBox1.Lines.Count = 50 Then
    textBox1.Lines= textBox1.Lines.Skip(Of String)(1).Take(textBox1.Lines.Length - 1).ToArray()
End If
```

**NOTE:** It will only work if you have framework 3.5 or above.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
dim sNewLine as String '-------> inserted text 
dim s as string = textbox1.text

s=mid(s,instr(s,vbCRLF)+2)
```

To append new line

```
textbox1.text = s & vbCRLF & sNewLine
```

Comment: Once VB6 ruled the world, but now there is VB.NET

Comment: I am currently learning VB.net, so if you could explain what this exactly does, would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Steve : Yeah .. it's an old way

Comment: @Gutanoth : It's been edited .. var 's' is what you need .. you can see reference about instr() function ..

Comment: It's still the old way to do it.  It's better to use the overloadable string methods than these days than things like mid() and instr()

Comment: @Steve VB6 never ruled the world ;-p

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
If TextBox1.Lines.Count = 50 Then
    Dim temp As String(50)
    Array.Copy(TextBox1.Lines,1,temp,0,49)
    TextBox1.Lines = temp
End If

TextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & "Current status : " & currentStatus)
```

I'm running on brain compiler and an iPhone at the moment, but I think that should work.

Comment: I get the following error: 'Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Copy' accepts this number of arguments'

Comment: My apologies.  I left a parameter off the `Array.Copy()` call.  I've edited the answer.

Comment: This also works! howver, chosen another answer due to the textchanged event